# Белый экран при компиляции в APK (PhoneGap Build) приложения на Angular

Tags: angularjs, phonegap, cordova, apk

Пишу приложуху, простую, без `Ionic`, на `Angular 1.5`: пару запросов `JSON` и выводом на 5-6 вьюх, каталог товаров и ничего более. Но после того, как закидываю в компилятор `PhoneGap Build`, выдает нормальный `apk`, в дебагере пусто. Закидываю на телефон, устанавливаю, все отлично - иконка и название есть. Запускаю и ... БЕЛЫЙ ЭКРАН. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не учел? Может надо писать контролеры в обертке какой-нибудь?

Comment: то, что есть иконка и название - это значит, что манифест правильно прописан. Но  не говорит о работоспособности приложения.

Попытайтесь сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример, удаляя код понемножку.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. В моём случае, было то, что пустой `localStorage` на телефоне и заполненый на компьюторе.

Поэтому, перед компиляцией очищайте кэш.